# Trying to search in Photoshop getting error : Something went wrong type error cannot read properties of undefined reading quickselect. how to fix?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to get to the  Discover Panel, but no matter what I tried I can't search. It's showing this error.

I'm on Windows 11 pro using Photoshop 24.1.0

I tried to click in the upper right corner search icon. I tried Cmd/Ctrl + F. I also tried Help -> Photoshop Help.

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  it's a basic customer support question, better addressed to Adobe.